# Android -- how to hide some activity on the basis of type of user

Tags: android

I want to display specific options in navigation drawer based on type of user i.e admin or user.
Admin to see all the options but users to see less activities.

Answer (score 0):

add navigation drawer items programatically depending upon the type of user.

i.e. if normal user or admin user then load respective array of drawer items.

Answer (score 0):

Use `NavigationView` Read more on it here [NavigationView | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html)

So your layout xml will be like:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

 <!-- Your contents -->

 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
     android:id="@+id/navigation"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_gravity="start"
     app:menu="@menu/menu_non_admin" />
 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Take notice of `app:menu` attribute of NavigationView. Over there set the general menu item for non-admins

Then in your activity get a reference to the navigation view and do this:

```
NavigationView nav = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);

// check if user is admin
if (user.isAdmin()) { // use your own logic to check if user is admin
    nav.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_admin); // supposing you have created the admin menu too
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to put all the options into the menu resource file (including the options only admins should see) and then programmatically hide the ones that "regular" users aren't supposed to see. For example:

menu_nav.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/user_admin"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_user_admin"
            android:title="@string/title_user_admin" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/sales"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_sales"
            android:title="@string/title_sales" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/profile"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_profile"
            android:title="@string/title_profile" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_map"
            android:title="@string/title_map" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

And then in your activity's `onCreate()`, after you call

```
navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
```

Then call

```
navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.user_admin).setVisible(false);
```

Do that for every menu item you want hidden.